# If a friend allows me the right to store property on his property but eventually tires of this agreement, can he legally deny me access to my property

Tags: contract-law, property, theft, repossession, demand-letter

He gave me a “24-hour” time period to retrieve my property when he knew I would be busy and not able to.

He gave me keys to locks that sealed entrances to his property without my request for them.

He changed those locks when he tired of the agreement and removed the lock I purchased and won’t relinquish it.

I entrusted him with the “brain”(located inside his house) to the security camera I purchased/installed outside of his house. He disconnected the brain therefore rendering my camera useless. Also not relinquishing.

Calls the police on me for trespassing when I was there to ask if I can recover my property, can this be used against me in court if I sue him for theft?

Comment: You may rethink the use of the word “friend”.

Comment: Since you have a real case, you need a real lawyer.

Answer (score 3):

### Your “friend” cannot legally retain your property

What you have is a [bailment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailment) arrangement where your friend is the bailee and you are the bailor. There is a legal duty on the bailee to return the property to the bailor when the bailment ends, subject to any legitimate [liens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lien) the bailee might have.

They do not have to allow you to “come and get it” but they do have to make reasonable arrangements to transfer the goods back to you. Giving you a single 24-hour time period is probably not reasonable.

However, you are not allowed to break the law to recover your property. The correct legal option is to ask a court to issue an order allowing you or the bailiff/sheriff (depending on where you are in the world) to lawfully enter into the property and collect the goods.

Comment: What are the circumstances (if any exist) that would constitute a denial for the bailor to remain the rightful owner and to recover the property? 
What evidence would be needed to prove that the bailor has no right to recover the property?

Comment: @TaronGlover if you have a question, ask a question; don’t leave a comment